# ReactJs : data from child to parent component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I start learning React, but i have some difficulty to figure out this error.
I have a parent component **Weather** and a child component **WeatherForm**. From the parent component i set a property for the child component. The child component is a form, and the goal is to get the text from an input and when the user clicks the submit button, the input text is passed to a function of the parent component which displays an alert with the text.

This is the parent component:

```
const WeatherForm = require('WeatherForm');
const WeatherMessage = require('WeatherMessage');

class Weather extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        location: ''
    };
    this.handleSearch = this.handleSearch.bind(this);
}
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h3>Weather component</h3>
            <WeatherForm onSearch={this.handleSearch} />
            <WeatherMessage />
        </div >
    );
}

handleSearch(value) {
    alert(value);
}


}
```

And this is the child component:

```
class WeatherForm extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onFormSubmit = this.onFormSubmit.bind(this);
}
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit}>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter a city name" ref="location" onChange={this.onFormSubmit}/>
                <button>Get weather</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}
onFormSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let location = this.refs.location;

    if (location.value && location.value.length > 0) {
        this.refs.location.value = '';
        props.onSearch(location.value);
    }

}
}
```

But when i click the submit button, i am getting this error:

> props.onSearch is not a function

Where I am making mistake?

I am also using the the parent component **Weather** in a Route in another component like this `<Route exact path="/" component={Weather} />`

Thanks to all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are missing the this context for your function call.

change `props.onSearch` to `this.props.onSearch`

reflected in your handler

```
onFormSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const value = this.refs.location.value;

    if (value && value.length > 0) {
        this.refs.location.value = '';
        this.props.onSearch(value);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks you guy. You make me also realize that I was using **OnSearch** with capital O instead of the real name **onSearch**.